# Transposons, Viruses and RNA interference

Tags: virology, rna-interference

My textbook says that in RNAi, a complementary double stranded RNA sequence attaches to an mRNA and silences it using a protein machinery. I Googled and read about this so now I know what siRNA and RISC and microRNA are. But the next thing my book says is

> “*the source of these complementary double stranded RNA
>   sequence* [obviously my textbook means siRNA] *may be viruses and
>   transposable elements*.”

What does this mean? Do transposons make siRNA? I thought transposons were non-coding except when they travel via the retrotransposon mechanism.

Do viruses that infect eukaryotic cells donate their own RNA genetic material for the cell to use in RNAi? But I thought RNAi was a cellular defence ***against*** viruses, how can viruses help give the dsRNA that’s supposed to fight the viruses? A number of sites online simply state that siRNA is exogenous is origin; do they mean that it comes from viruses?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take the time to answer each of my questions one by one or even recommend a site that answers them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transposons and viruses don't "make siRNA". However, an endonuclease called [Dicer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicer) can process dsRNA from these sources to produce [siRNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_interfering_RNA) which is then loaded to the RNA-induced silencing complex ([RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA-induced_silencing_complex)) to suppress propagation of viruses and transposons. The following papers provide a good overview:

[Buchon N, Vaury C. 2006. RNAi: a defensive RNA-silencing against viruses and transposable elements. Heredity 96:195-202.](http://www.nature.com/hdy/journal/v96/n2/full/6800789a.html)

[van Rij RP, Andino R. 2006. The silent treatment: RNAi as a defense against virus infection in mammals. Trends Biotechnol 24:186-193.](http://www.cell.com/trends/biotechnology/fulltext/S0167-7799(06)00051-5)

[image]